# I am getting Error while using FedEx Tracking Number for Delivered Status

Tags: c#

I have used FedEx testing Tracking Number for Delivered status. But I am getting below error message. Except delivered other status are getting correct response

> Severity: ERROR  Code: 9040  Message: This tracking number cannot be
>   found. Please check the number or contact the sender.  Source: trck
>   Tracking number: 122816215025810 Tracking number unique identifier:
>   Track Status:  () Carrier code: FDXC Package Sequence Number: 0
>   Package Count: 0

Can anybody help with this?

Comment: Well, I just tried your tracking number on FedEx's website, and it wasn't found.  So what do you expect?

Comment: As @rory.ap pointed out, you get that error message because it's true. Are you saying that once the package is delivered the tracking number is removed from FedEx's system? If so, how quickly are they being removed?

Answer (score 1):

[I tried your tracking number on FedEx's website](https://www.fedex.com/apps/fedextrack/?tracknumbers=122816215025810&cntry_code=us) and it doesn't exist, hence your error message.

Answer (score 0):

Fedex Carrier Code needs to match the tracking number. For example tracking numbers formatted as 2813.... will work with FDXG Carrier code while ones that start with 6129.... work with FXSP.